# How to count same number of pictures using jQuery after selecting from option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have drop down from different selection menus and when any option is selected its picture is loaded. e.g see pic:

[image]

Now my problem is to find how many times did I selected the same option Or how many pictures with same name there are inside in divs. Trying in both ways but failed to get proper way.

i tried this `var count = $("#some_id").find('img').length;` but everytime gives no proper value. Also i m trying to place global counter `myFuncCalls` but doing so it only counts number of total selection not specific such as there are two apples has been selected but it gives 3. Rather 2.

here is my code HTML:

```
<select id="fruits" name="fruits[]" class="form-control" style="width:19%;float:left;">
  <option value="">Fruit</option>
  <option value="Apple" onclick="pic('apple.png','apple',0);">Apple</option>
  <option value="Apple Black Currant" onclick="pic('AppleBlackCurrant.png','AppleBlackCurrant',0);">Apple</option>      
</select>

<select name="menuItems[]" id="Strawberry" class="form-control" style="width:19%;float:left;" onchange="">
  <option value="">Recess </option>
  <option value="Milk Strwaberry" onclick="pic('MilkStrwaberry.png','MilkStrwaberry',0);">Milk Strwaberry</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
//same for other
//v is picture
//name is picturename
//flag for yes or no
function pic(v, names, flag) { //alert(flag);
  //alert($(".fruits option:selected[value='"+names+"']").length);
  if (flag == 1) {
    if (myFuncCalls > 0) {
      alert("You can only select one item from each category");
      return false;
    } else {
      myFuncCalls++;
      // alert('s'+v);
      //alert(myFuncCalls);
      $("#image1").prepend('<div id="c" class="thumbnail" style="width:20%;float:left;background: rgb(238, 238, 238) none repeat scroll 0px 0px;"><img class="remove-img glyphicon glyphicon-remove" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/cross.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" ><img id="imgpic" src="<?php echo '
        http: //localhost:8080/catering/uploads/'?>'+ v +' " style="width:100px"></div>');
        $('.remove-img').click(function (e) {
          $(this).parent().find('img').remove();
          myFuncCalls = 0;
        });
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0) { //0 means No
      myFuncCalls++;
      // alert('s'+v);
      //alert(myFuncCalls);
      $("#image1").prepend('<div id="c" class="thumbnail" style="width:20%;float:left;background: rgb(238, 238, 238) none repeat scroll 0px 0px;"><img class="remove-img glyphicon glyphicon-remove" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/cross.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" ><img id="imgpic" src="<?php echo '
        http: //localhost:8080/catering/uploads/'?>'+ v +' " style="width:100px"></div>');

        $('.remove-img').click(function (e) {
          $(this).parent().find('img').remove();
          myFuncCalls = 0;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How about creating a variable for every fruit to count like var appleCount, then add a condition to your function: if (name == 'apple') {appleCount++}

Comment: but wt if other also comes in dynamic form from db then wt do i ve to do at that time?

Comment: that was just a simple illustration

Comment: Then you can store the value coming into the db into a variable then use that variable